# Clear the 'comment' field after successful TFS check-in?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, visual-studio-2013

In Visual Studio 2013, is it possible to have TFS automatically clear the 'Comment' field after a successful check-in (on the Pending Changes panel)?

Currently, I just  manually highlight and delete the comment field text after every check-in.

Example below.

Added a comment to my check-in...

[image: TFS check-in with comment]

Would like to see this after a successful check-in (along with the cleared 'Included Changes' pane)...

[image: TFS check-in with a cleared comment field]

Comment: Why are you deleting comments on changesets? Would you not like to know later on what was changed in  each changeset?

Comment: Are you doing Gated Checkins?

Comment: @DaveShaw Yes, I am doing gated check-ins.

Comment: @Hamid Shahid I don't delete the comment from the changeset, I am just clearing the text from the comment field.

Comment: @zacc206 Are you preserving the changes locally and reconciling the checkin?

Comment: @DaveShaw i do reconcile locally after check-in, which clears the 'Included Changes' pane but the comment field still has my last comment