# Check In fields are not getting cleared after the Gated Check In is successful

Tags: tfs

Even we are having the same issue fields are not getting cleared after the Gated Check In developer has to delete field values manually. Anyone has solution for this issue?

Refer - [Clear the 'comment' field after successful TFS check-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23274721/clear-the-comment-field-after-successful-tfs-check-in/36546784#36546784)

Answer (score 0):

No way to clear the comment for a Gated Checkin unless uncheck `Preserve my pending changes locally`. But in this way, you'll have to perform `Get latest` for the file as the changes are not preserved locally.

I suggest you submit a feature request on [User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015).

[image]